# Is it possible to write a script to run an application on Windows VM from your mac?

Tags: windows, macos, automation, remote-desktop

I am using a RDC Connection from my mac to connect to an application (on windows box) in client network. Is that possible to write a script which does the following:

1. Open ur RDC. (i am using CoRD for this where my VM credentials are saved in .rdp files.
2. Login to VM with valid credentials from your .rdp file.
3. Open your app on that VM (for ex: IE explorer)

Following code in my shell script will connect me to my VM.(First two steps are working)

```
open rdp://[username[:password]@]hostname
```

How should I automate third step?
Is there any other way than shell script?

Answer (score 0):

If you install [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) on your Mac, then install the Jenkins slave agent on the Windows machine, you can remotely run any command you like on the Windows box via the Jenkins web UI, and get back the results as well. In that scenario there's no need to use RDC at all.

For some more background, see: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simplistic answer, but **[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)** is something that will automate your 3rd step. Its free and pretty easy to script. You can have this in your start up routine for your VM, so when you log in, you can have this kick off your job.

I have used it before for testing some Java Swing components on Windows and its been pretty handy (Windows was running on a Virtualbox VM on my Mac).